# problem downloading movie to iphone for storage and playback

Tags: iphone, download, movie

I am basically making a video library where you download videos and I then write them to the applications documents folder. This all works fine and if i stream the video from online it plays fine. Or indeed I can stream it from the resource folder fine.

However, after downloading it and saving to the documents folder then attempting to stream I get the error 'movie format not supported' any ideas?

thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your code fails to write the file successfully. Did you checked the size of the file (and does it match the size of the video).

However: If the video format isn't a supported one, this wont work at all ;)

Comment: great idea, will check the size now